# How can i use "DisplayAlert" using Caliburn.Micro 3.0 and Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, caliburn.micro

I'm a long time Caliburn.Micro WPF user and now I have started looking into Xamarin.Forms.

I've got Caliburn.Micro 3.0 working with Xamarin.Forms but I haven't found any way or built in service to call the Xamarin.Forms function "DisplayAlert(...)" that you normally call from the code behind of your Page.

Do I have to build this myself for now? Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for this already Allan Ritchie made, which can be found here: https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs

I suppose Caliburn Micro provides its own way to register things with the IoC container. As described in the link above you will need to register the types userdialogs provides with it.

So in MvvmCross you register the interface like this:

```
Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IUserDialogs>(() => UserDialogs.Instance);
```

With Caliburn I think it is something like:

```
_container.RegisterInstance(typeof(IUserDialogs), "dialogs", UserDialogs.Instance);
```

If you opt not to use this plugin, you could implement your own `IUserDialogs` interface with your own implementation and register it with the IoC and make it accessible in your ViewModels through injection or by looking it up directly with the IoC.

Comment: Thank you, seems very nice! I guess it shouldn't be too hard to use with Caliburn. 

However I still wonder if the Caliburn team will include a service that calls the Xamarin.Forms built in "DisplayAlert" method...?